# Gesture clears when orientation changed

Tags: android, database, orientation, config, gesture

I have a gestureOverlayView in my layout which I am using for drawing digital Signature. The problem arises when I draw in a certain orientation (say landscape) and then change the orientation - the overlayView just clears. I have tried including onConfigurationChanged();but no effect. I have also attempted the following with onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance, but it gives me no solution:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Gesture gesture = overlay.getGesture();
    outState.putParcelable("gesture", (Parcelable) gesture);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Gesture gesture = (Gesture) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("gesture");
    overlay.setGesture(gesture);
    mDoneButton.setEnabled(true);
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I have also tried including:

```
  android:configChanges="fontScale|uiMode|screenLayout|navigation|touchscreen|mcc|mnc|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
```

But even this is of no use.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hey Thanks for the edit Jon. Can you also help me get an answer for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code in my application and had the same issue. The result of getGesture() is null within onSaveInstanceState, onStop, and onPause, so I'm guessing that the GestureOverlayView is invalidated somewhere between the screen rotation and the calling of those methods.

A workaround is to override onGesturePerformed, assuming your Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener and you call addOnGesturePerformedListener(this) on your overlay, and save a member instance of the most recent Gesture. Something like:

```
    @Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    mCurrentGesture = gesture;
    }
```

Then in your onSaveInstanceState, simply get and package the member instance instead of calling getGesture(). Now setGesture() should work as expected when the Activity recreates itself.

Comment: hey thnx .. I'll try to implement this myself

Answer (score 1):

Use android:configChanges="fontScale|uiMode|screenLayout|navigation|touchscreen|mcc in manifest or try onSavedInstance;

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation changes it restarts the activity. You could try restrict the orientation of the app in the manifest file.

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: Hey thanks. But I don't want to restrict the orientation.I want to retain the gesture in case of change in orientation.